# How to queue up websocket messages through forked worker and simultaneously process them one by one in main loop in Node js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, websocket, fork, cryptocurrency

I am writing a crypto trading bot that is required to listen to websocket streams (orderbook changes, trade executions etc.). On every event, the websocket should save the incoming message in an array and call the main logic loop to process the message.

While the logic code is executing, if more messages are received, they should be queued up in an array (saved somewhere) and they should not immediately call up the main loop. Idea is that once main loop is done with the processing, it can look up the queue array and pick the next message to process. This way no messages will be lost. Also main logic loop won't be called multiple times if multiple messages arrive while it is already working.

I am using the following code but not able to achieve the desired architecture.

```
    webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
        var msg = {
            "op": "authKeyExpires",
            "args": ["somekey", nonce, signature + ""]
        };
        
        webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
        
        webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({"op":"subscribe", "args":["orderBookApi:BTCPFC_0"]}));
    };
          
      webSocket.onmessage = async function(e) {
        queue.push(JSON.parse(e.data));
        
        main_logic(queue);
      }

async function main_logic(queue){
//process the next message in the queue and then delete it. Keep doing it till queue is empty.
}
```

I have read that maybe forking or worker process for websocket can help. Kindly advise as I am new to node js and programming in general.